# Do ships get progressively harder in rebel-controlled nodes in the same Sector?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

Just curious after actually getting a really nice combo'd ship that could decimate fleets without being touched -- I'm honestly curious if chilling inside rebel-controlled nodes will scale enemies constantly?

Say you are in Sector 3, where enemies are more likely to have 1-2 shields and missile/laser weapons. If I were to just hang around jumping from node to node to fight rebel scum, would the ships get harder and harder up to 4 shield/4 weapon ones like in Sector 7-8?

Comment: This is actually a very interesting question. I searched a bit but I don't think there's a canonical answer. The only way to find out is to try it out.

Comment: Why do you think they might?

Comment: I figured the game might want to induce players to hop into the next sector, rather than hang around to farm resources. Although it wouldn't be easy considering every node has artillery fire from rebel artillery.

Comment: @senpai If you're diving into the rebel fleet, I'm pretty sure the only reward you get for fights is 1 fuel, with a message that says you don't have time to scavenge for more.

Comment: *Not* upgrading your shields is one of the ways to 'cheat' (up to a certain sector; I forget which). They will always have one more than you, and never more than that, until sector 3 or w/e it is. And iirc it doesn't change until you jump to another sector. So, "in the same sector", idts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I highly doubt that the Elite Fighters get any more difficult if you hang around in a sector, jumping between rebel-controlled beacons. Difficulty of enemy ships is usually based on the difficulty setting, and what sector you're in.
There's no reward for defeating the ships at Rebel-Controlled beacons other than 1 fuel anyway, so there's not much point deliberately hanging around.

Hope this helps.